# How can I manipulate the number of decimal places in the frame ticks?

Tags: plotting, ticks

Is there any simple way to increase or decrease the decimal places in the frame ticks. I want to make the y axis ticks of the first two and the second two graphs look similar.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately it seems you have to do this manually, by creating `FrameTicks` or processing already created `FrameTicks` with `NumberForm` e.g. Related: [tick label precision](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6925/how-to-set-tick-label-precision/6926#6926), [number format in ticks](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5369/5478), [customize your frame ticks](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/23763/5478).

Comment: hm, I should've read your comment before answering, it definitely looks like a duplicate...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way to do this would be to explicitly state where you want your ticks to go along with exactly how you want them labelled.  For example, consider the following plot

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2*Pi}, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

Let's have points only at -1, 0 and 1 and have them displayed to three decimal places

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2*Pi}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameTicks -> {{{{-1, "-1.000"}, {0, "0.000"}, {1, "1.000"}}, 
    Automatic}, {Automatic, None}}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 14):

I'd like to present another approach I like to use, when it comes to styling ticks:

**Define a `tickFormat` function**

We define a function that formats the ticks we want to use (so that we don't have to specify them manually, later on).

```
tickFormat[xmin_, xmax_, digits_, divisions_: 10] := 
    Function[tickNumber, {tickNumber, 
       PaddedForm[Round[tickNumber, 0.01], 
         {Max@(Length@IntegerDigits@IntegerPart[#] & /@ 
         (10^digits {xmin, xmax})), digits}]
     }] /@ FindDivisions[{xmin, xmax}, divisions];
```

I am sure you'll easily see how it works and how you could possibly customize this account.

Note: I introduced 2 auxiliary variables to `tickFormat`, i.e. the 3rd variable controls the number of digits after the decimal separator to be displayed and the 4th (optional) argument specifies the number of ticks `FindDivisions` will insert (note: this can slightly vary, see documentation of [`FindDivisions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FindDivisions.html))

**Application**

*All "frame-axes"*

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 20 \[Pi]}, Axes -> False, Frame -> True, 
    FrameTicks -> (tickFormat[#1, #2, 3, 10] &)]
```

[image]

*y-Axis only*

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 20 \[Pi]}, Axes -> False, Frame -> True, 
     FrameTicks -> {Automatic, (tickFormat[#1, #2, 5, 12] &), None, None}]
```

[image]

**Note**

This works on normal axes just as shown for "FrameAxes"

Answer (score 9):

Here is the code I use to style ticks, including a `DecimalPadding` option that uses the in-built `NumberForm` functionality to generate the desired look.

```
Options[myTickGrid] = {UnitLabelShift -> 1.4, DecimalPadding -> 0};

myTickGrid[min_?NumericQ, max_?NumericQ, seg_, units_, len_: 0, 
  opts : OptionsPattern[{myTickGrid, NumberForm}]] := 
 With[{dec = OptionValue[DecimalPadding]}, 
  Table[{i, If[i == max, makeUnitLabel[units, 
      Sequence @@ FilterRules[{opts}, Options[myTickGrid]]], 
     mynumberformat[i, dec, 
      Sequence @@ FilterRules[{opts}, Options[NumberForm]]]], {len, 0}}, 
    {i, If[Head[seg] === List, Union[{min, max}, seg], 
     Range[min, max, seg]]}]]

unitlab2 = 
  2.2;(*the amount of additional downshift needed to align the top of \
the unit label to the top of the plot area when the unit label has a \
line break in it*)
unitlabls = {0.9, -5};(*linespacing for unit labels*)

makeUnitLabel[units_, opts : OptionsPattern[{myTickGrid}]] := 
 DisplayForm[AdjustmentBox[Style[units, LineSpacing -> unitlabls], 
   BoxBaselineShift -> OptionValue[UnitLabelShift] + 
     If[StringFreeQ[units, "\n"], 0, unitlab2]]]

mynumberformat[n_?NumericQ, q_Integer?Positive, 
  opts : OptionsPattern[{NumberForm}]] := 
 Switch[n, _Integer, 
  NumberForm[N[n], {Max[0, Last@RealDigits[N[n]]] + q, q}, 
   Sequence @@ FilterRules[{opts}, Options[NumberForm]], 
   DigitBlock -> 3, NumberSeparator -> "\[ThinSpace]"], _, 
  NumberForm[N[n], {Max[0, Last@RealDigits[N[n]]] + q, q}, 
   Sequence @@ FilterRules[{opts}, Options[NumberForm]]]]
(*Needs Max[] with zero because approximate zero yields negative \
number in RealDigits output*)

mynumberformat[n_?NumericQ, opts : OptionsPattern[{NumberForm}]] := 
 Switch[n, _Integer, 
  NumberForm[n, Sequence @@ FilterRules[{opts}, Options[NumberForm]], 
   DigitBlock -> 3, NumberSeparator -> "\[ThinSpace]"], 
          _, NumberForm[N[n], Sequence @@ FilterRules[{opts}, Options[NumberForm]]]]

mynumberformat[n_?NumericQ, Automatic, 
  opts : OptionsPattern[{NumberForm}]] := mynumberformat[n, opts]

mynumberformat[n_?NumericQ, 0, opts : OptionsPattern[{NumberForm}]] :=
  mynumberformat[n, opts]
```

Let's try this with some fake data.

```
fakedata = 
  Transpose@{DatePlus[{2001, 1}, {#, "Month"}] & /@ Range[0, 99], 
    Accumulate[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], {100}]]};
```

Here is a simple example with decimal places on one side and not the other, to demonstrate usage.

```
DateListPlot[fakedata, Joined -> True, PlotRange -> {-6, 6}, 
 FrameTicks -> {{myTickGrid[-6, 6, 2, "%", 0.02, DecimalPadding -> 1],
     myTickGrid[-6, 6, 2, "%", 0.02]}, {Automatic, None}}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

How about this?

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2*Pi}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameTicks -> 
  Append[Append[
    Round[#, 0.001] & /@ {Range[0, 2 Pi, 2 Pi/4], 
      Range[-1, 1, 0.3]}, None], None]]
```

[image]