# how to deal with so many digits in plot ticks

Tags: plotting

the data is as follows

```
data = {{{25, 0.0000234834`}, {45, 0.0000127008`}, {65, 
0.0000104495`}, {85, 9.68187`*^-6}, {105, 9.3519`*^-6}}, {{25, 
0.0000210205`}, {45, 0.0000159071`}, {65, 0.0000148415`}, {85, 
0.0000144786`}, {105, 0.0000143227`}}, {{25, 1.74304`*^-6}, {45, 
1.74268`*^-6}, {65, 1.74261`*^-6}, {85, 1.74259`*^-6}, {105, 
1.74258`*^-6}}, {{25, 4.26787`*^-6}, {45, 3.95165`*^-6}, {65, 
3.88582`*^-6}, {85, 3.86343`*^-6}, {105, 3.85382`*^-6}}, {{25, 
3.29821`*^-6}, {45, 3.1484999999999996`*^-6}, {65, 
3.1174400000000003`*^-6}, {85, 3.1069`*^-6}, {105, 
3.10239`*^-6}}, {{25, 2.4761199999999996`*^-6}, {45, 
2.4761199999999996`*^-6}, {65, 2.4761199999999996`*^-6}, {85, 
2.4761199999999996`*^-6}, {105, 2.4761199999999996`*^-6}}}
```

and

```
ListLogPlot[data]
```

gives

[image: img]

There are some useless digits like "00000" in the tick. How to prevent this situation automatically?

**Edit**

I found an interesting thing, If you <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> the Plot again. Then the 00000 are gone and become scientific form.

[image: img2]

Comment: I strongly recommend to create a function, like `tickFormat` by PinguinDirk from [decimal places in FrameTicks](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/33299/5478). Also, in this Q&A there is my comment to other strongly related topics.

Comment: @matheorem Yes I would go for PinguinDirk's answer. Perhaps you can automate it if your plots are all more or less similar.

Comment: @Kuba: thanks for the flowers :) I've recently been so inactive, I even forgot the answers I posted myself... good thing you are more active and have the overview of the community!

Comment: @PinguinDirk No problem, I usually remember answers that taught me something :)

Comment: @Kuba @SjoerdC.deVries Thank you for your information! I learned to style ticks. A custom `tickformat` is useful.

Answer (score 3):

Why not multiply by 10^6 and then label the Y axes as times 10^-6?

```
data[[All, All, 2]] = data[[All, All, 2]] 10^6
ListLogPlot[data, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"X-axes", 
   "Y (\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(10\), \(-6\)]\))"}]
```

[image]

Comment: this is a possible way, thank you for your suggestion